# How to efficiently run a summary query in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb-query

Using MongoDB, I need to perform a query equivalent to the following SQL query (in Python):

```
SELECT person, SUM(score)
From demo
GROUP BY person
HAVING SUM(score) > 0
```

What would be the most efficient method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-group-count-and-sort-example/) is a good reference for applying aggregation on MongoDB.

In your case assuming there is `demo` collection:

```
db.demo.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$person",
           totalScore: { $sum: "$score" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Comment: How long will it take to run this query on a collection of 10K-100K of documents?